# linux nasm assembly endlessly printing character

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am writing a program to get an integer from the user, and then print out all the numbers from 0 up to the number. My code gets the input fine, but when printing it out, it prints continuously in what seems to be an endless loop. Here is my code:

```
SECTION .data           ; Constant variable declaration
len   EQU 32        ; Constant length
msg db "Enter a number: ", 0 ; Input message
msglen EQU $-msg             ; Input message length

SECTION .bss            ; Uninitialised data declaration
other resd len      ; Output counter that is incremented
data  resd len      ; Input data buffer 

SECTION .text           ; Main program initialiser

GLOBAL _start           ; Linker entry point declaration
_start:                 ; Entry point
nop                 ; This keeps the debugger happy :)

Msg:                    ; This section prints out the message
mov eax, 4          ; }
mov ebx, 1          ; }
mov ecx, msg        ; } System_write call
mov edx, msglen     ; }
int 80h             ; }

input:                  ; This section gets the integer from the user
mov eax, 3          ; }
mov ebx, 0          ; }
mov ecx, data       ; } System_read call
mov edx, len        ; }
int 80h             ; }

ASCIIAdj:   
mov ebp, 48         ; This line sets the counter to '0' ASCII

setup:                  ; This section adjusts the counter
mov [other], ebp    ; Increment counter 

loop:                   ; This section loops, printing out from zero to the number given
mov eax, 4          ; }
mov ebx, 1          ; }
mov ecx, other      ; } System_write call
mov edx, len        ; }
int 80h             ; }
mov eax, 1          ; Move 1 to eax
add ebp, eax        ; Add eax to ebp (essentially increment ebp)
    mov eax, other      ; move other to eax
    mov ebx, data       ; move data to ebx
    cmp eax, ebx        ; compare them
jne setup           ; If they are not the same, go back to the setup to increment other

exit:                   ; Exits the program
mov eax, 1          ; }
mov ebx, 0          ; } System_exit call
int 80h             ; }
```

Why does it loop continuously? I have incremented the counter, and compared the input and the counter, so why doesn't it break?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Expected Output:

```
Enter a number: 6
0123456
```

General Semantics of the program:

```
Display "Enter a number: "
Read in an integer less than 32 bytes in size.
Set a counter variable to the ASCII value of zero
Loop:
Display the character, adding 1 to it, and checking to see if it is equal to the value    inputted.
If it is equal, goto the exit section and exit
Else loop.
```

Comment: Try to use a debugger like `gdb` to step by step machine instructions

Comment: It is hard to comprehend the semantics of the program.  What does `other` mean?  It looks to be a 32 byte buffer, but sometimes a 16-bit integer is written into it; other places its address is compared.  I can't tell what is right and wrong.

Comment: `other` is a counter variable that I am using to display the numbers less than the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is digging waaaay back into the deep dark recesses of my memory, but I think you want

```
mov eax, [other]      ; move other to eax
mov ebx, [data]       ; move data to ebx
```

Note the brackets, which are missing in your code.  You are loading the *addresses* of `other` and `data` into `eax` and `ebx`, not the values contained there.

Comment: It now does not loop endlessly, it sprays out about 200 characters that end with the numbers 0 up to the inputted number. How can I get rid of all those initial characters?

Comment: Just a suggestion... When you do `mov edx, len`, you tell sys_write to print 32 characters. You probably only want 1 here.